# What is the best way to atomic-replace all contents in List in Java?

Tags: java, list, caching, collections, concurrency

Suppose that I have a `List` with role of cache. Most time list is **read-only** buy every few seconds I want to do **atomic** replacement of all List contents.

In atomic I mean that I don't want to allow cache clients to hit read between for example `clear()` and `addAll()`.

What list implementation to use and how to perform replacement for best performance?

It is better to replace list contents or to replace reference value itself?

Comment: I like your 2nd option better, you'll have the reference locked for a much shorter duration.

Answer (score 3):

Java has a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) which supports reads concurrently and writes exclusively. As mentioned in the JavaDoc, it is a good choice if updates occur not very frequently and reads occur often. The faster your writer updates the `List` the better the performance you get.

The methods readLock() has to be called by readers and writeLock() by writers. Then you have to call lock() on the Lock obtained. If it is available, the tread will continue working, otherwise it will block, until the lock is available.

Use fairness when constructing the `ReadWriteLock` to enable reader and writer threads to obtain their locks in the order they requested it. Otherwise some thread could wait forever (in a worst case scenario).

The benefit of a `ReadWriteLock` is that many reader may share the same lock without obtaining it, which is an expansive operation. This benefit is only observable if the ratio between reading and writing is heavily in favor of reading.

Comment: Will it be faster than just changin volatile reference to new list object?

Comment: The Java volatile keyword only ensures that many threads reading the same shared data will have to update any locally cached values of that data. It does not provide any synchronization mechanism as far as I am aware of. Maybe you are interested in reading this [example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-volatile-keyword-0) about the volatile keyword, which I think is a very good one.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the `List<>` type for a cache, you can use a lock like:

```
private static final Objet cacheLock  = new Object();


 public void updateListCache()
 {
    synchronized(lock)
    {
       //update your list cache
    }

 }
```

Your read operation would also need to implement this lock, or it wouldn't be much use.

But for caching purposes I would personally go with [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) since it's thread safe.